# Carry a sentiment

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Assume we are discussing about something and a statement is being quoted and everyone has his own interpretations of it.

Can I say "that statement does not *carry your sentiment*."?
to indicate that I think that statement is different from their interpretation?

Comment: I would use "convey" instead of "carry."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to say that someone's statement doesn't really support their interpretation of some subject, then "sentiment" is not the word I would use.  "Sentiment" refers more to general *feelings* and *concepts* than *intellectual analysis.*  For example:

> I share her **sentiment** that this new government plan will make things worse in the long run.  (= I *feel* the way she *feels* about the plan)

"Carry your sentiment" doesn't *say what you mean to say* -- which is a good way to express this feeling.

> I think what you are telling us doesn't **say what you mean to say**.

Other possibilities

> it **doesn't properly express** your (thoughts | intentions | interpretations | beliefs | etc.)
>
> it **doesn't accurately convey** your (thoughts | etc.)
>
> it **doesn't really reflect** your (thoughts | etc.)

and others.

Comment: Thanks! Can we use "carry" with "sentiment" at all?

Comment: @dandikain  Yes, but not in this context.  You can say that something *carries great sentimental value*, for example.  A better verb for what you are trying to say might be *convey (my) sentiments* meaning it "expresses (my) feelings".